# Find exact time of crash from fabric.io crashlytics dashboard

Tags: android, crashlytics, crash-reports, crashlytics-android, fabric.io

me and my team is trying to find out at what time crash occurred on particular date. On crashlytics dashboard its showing only date.

[image]

We want to know exact time to make sure unexpected behavior of app is because of this bug only as we are not able to reproduce this bug. 
If any one know how to find out exact time of crash it will be of great help.
we are using `fabric.io`

[image]

Comment: I have searched...but the time is only visible when crash has been reported within last 24 hours of span from now.

Answer (score 0):

From the Fabric dashboard, select the issue, then click on "View all sessions" and you'll see the timestamp in the top-left corner in UTC time.

[image: Timestamp visible in Fabric dashboard]